# How to create a custom require that can be recreated

Tags: c++, lua

I created my custom `require` function in Lua but when I create the function multiple times, it doesn't seem to replace the previously created `require` function.

I would like to be able to replace(or overwrite) the previous `require` function time to time.

**My Code :**

```
#include "lua.hpp"

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaopen_my(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        luaL_dostring(L, "local require_original = require\n"
                         "function require(name, ...)\n"
                             "print('Hello World')\n"
                             "local val = table.pack(require_original(name, ...))\n"
                             "return table.unpack(val,1,val.n)\n"
                         "end\n");
        luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['A'] = function()\n"
                             "local a = {}\n"
                             "print('A required')\n"
                             "return a\n"
                         "end\n");
        luaL_dostring(L, "local a = require 'A'");
        luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['A'] = nil package.loaded['A'] = nil");
    }
    lua_close(L);
}
```

**The Result I get :**

```
Hello World
A required
Hello World
Hello World
A required
```

**The Result I expect :**

```
Hello World
A required
Hello World
A required
```

What should I change to get the result I expect?

Comment: I think the first time you are setting the *local* `require_original` to the *actual* lua require and setting the *global* require to your function.  The second time through you are setting *local* `require_original` to *your* require function and replacing *your* global function with a new copy.  So when you call `require()` it is calling 1) your newest require which calls 2) your first require which calls 3) the original require.  You could use global require_original to only set it once `require_original = require_original or require`

Comment: Why not create a new environment with a different `require` function?

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: @ZackLee Not really, it depends on how the rest of your code looks. It would be much easier to just read about it in the [Lua reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may provide special "uninstall" function in global namespace :-)
Replace Lua code inside first `luaL_dostring` with the following:

```
if uninstall_my_require then
   uninstall_my_require()
end
local require_original = require
local function my_require(name, ...)
   print('Hello World')
   local val = table.pack(require_original(name, ...))
   return table.unpack(val,1,val.n)
end
require = my_require 
function uninstall_my_require()
   if require == my_require then
      require = require_original
   end
   uninstall_my_require = nil
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The first time through you are setting global `require` function to your new function, the second time you are saving *your new function* and setting it to another instance.  It's like this in lua:

```
local require_original1 = require
function require(name, ...)
   print('Hello World')
   local val = table.pack(require_original1(name, ...))
   return table.unpack(val,1,val.n)
end

local require_original2 = require -- now the function above
function require(name, ...) -- redefine yet again
   print('Hello World')
   -- require_original2 is your function above
   local val = table.pack(require_original2(name, ...))
   return table.unpack(val,1,val.n)
end
```

You need to keep track of the original require function just once, either with an uninstall function like Egor's answer or change it to a global that is only assigned once:

```
require_original = require_original or require
```